# Kubernetes: how to discover neighbor pods

Tags: kubernetes, service-discovery

I have started 3 different pods (in GKE):

```
kubectl run ubuntu --image myimage --namespace misko -r 3 --command -- /some/binary --bind-to-port 1234
```

Now I need to discover hostnames/ip addresses of those pods from 4th pod which needs to connect to those 3 nodes.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is creating a [Deployment](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/) that will control the pods behaviour and replicas but you have to create a service for this deployment in order to  expose the ports inside or outside the cluster.

```
kubectl expose deployment ubuntu --port=1234 --target-port=1234
```

After that you can access the pods in round-robin using the service name and the port number:

```
ububtu:1234
```

If the other pod it's on a different namespace, you may use the full DNS instead:

```
ubuntu.misko.svc.cluster.local:1234
```

Please take a look at  [kubectl expose](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_expose/) for more examples

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of this solution, but the problem is I need to get IPs of all those pods (not using round robin). But now I realize it's a stupid idea from the design perspective and I should not do it.

Comment: You also can create 3 separate deployments with 3 different services and only one replica/deployment. Then use DNS.  Depends on what you are trying to achieve. In case of a restart, the IP will be changed.

Comment: I'm trying to create mongo replicas, but they are dependent on hostnames. That's unusable for Kubernetes.

Comment: There is a easier way to deploy mongodb in k8s using helm charts. You can find more info here: https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/incubator/mongodb and here: http://billcloud.me/deploying-mongodb-on-kubernetes-1.4-using-helm-charts/

Comment: @Misko Check out [PetSets](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/petset/) which may be closer to what you want.